# Understanding the scroll bar in the Firefox 'List All Tabs' dropdown

Tags: gui-design, firefox

I'm trying to understand the rationale behind the vertical scroll bar in the 'List All Tabs' dropdown in Firefox (15.0.1);

- All the tabs are listed here, so it gives the wrong impression of the list containing more elements than can be listed.
- It's not grab-able by the mouse pointer
- It's not location specific.  Selected a tab in the middle of the list, and the scrollbar will still be set hard against either the top or bottom (whatever was last selected).

I was wondering what other people think?  Is there a logical to this, I am missing?  Or is it a bug/inconsistency?

[image: Firefox 'List All Tabs' dropdown scrollbar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually not a scroll bar. It's an indicator to show which of the tabs are currently visible in the browser tab bar. The ones in the list outside the grey indicator are also outside the tab bar in the browser.

It's there to make it easier for users to orientate and look among the tabs that are currently not shown in the browser.

Try and use the < and > and navigate in the tab bar and you'll see that the bar has shifted place.

Comment: Probably not a great design, though - it does look like a type of scrollbar common on the web. I wonder if it would have been better to show only the tabs that weren't being displayed (after all, the real use of this control is to grab tabs that aren't being shown).

Comment: I see, it wasn't immediately obvious but now I understand.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye Showing only the tabs that weren't being displayed is a possible answer, and could work better as a metaphor.  In a sense of the drop down tabs list could be an overflow for what couldn't be displayed, I have seen that behavior in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Or perhaps they could annotate the vertical scroll bar (view indicator) with a little message ("Current View") ?

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye I definitely agree with you. The reasoning behind showing all open tabs is that users can see all tab names in their entirety. If a user has a number of tabs from the same domain open the tabs may all look the same in the tab bar, but in the list the user is able to set them apart.

Comment: @AndroidHustle Yes, I do tend to use the dropdown bar, as it's easier on the eye to look through a list, rather than across the breadth of my Firefox tab control at abbreviated tab descriptions.

Comment: @AndroidHustle - Hmm, I don't think that tool is the best way to show tab names. Firstly, I don't think users will understand it can be used that way (it sits at the end of the series, so it looks as though it pertains to the elements out of reach); secondly, I think there are probably better ways of letting users see tab names (eg expand on hover or tooltip), which I think users will find simpler to discover; thirdly, I think favicons already do a good job of helping users identify tabs anyhow. I still think it's not the best design.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye well, I'm not debating whether this is a good solution to browse tabs or not. I don't defend it, I have nothing to do with it, I'm simply the messenger saying why it is the way it is. I do however believe that for a LARGE amount of tabs, this list will definitely offer better/faster scannability than scanning through each individual tab through hover/tooltip states. Finding a tab among a many that way would very possibly prove tedious.

Comment: @AndroidHustle - I'm not attacking you. I just said I didn't think it was the best decision on Firefox's part.

Comment: @AndroidHustle - As for the design itself - it all depends why users want large tab names. It's true that it's more efficient to read a list than to hover one-by-one, but do users need to know the names of all tabs or just want disambiguation for individual ones? And just because a workflow might be more efficient doesn't mean users will use it - they satisfice instead. That can mean discoverability can trump plain efficiency - and hovers / tooltips might be more discoverable (though maybe improvements to the design of the dropdown could solve that).

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye oh no, I never thought you attacked me. I just wanted to point out that I didn't necessarily either think it was a good solution. I totally agree that the feature is probably unseen by a large amount of users, and on top of that I believe that scenarios where a user has a big number of tabs of the same domain open at the same time is probably also not that common either. I would also like to see another solution, but I suspect that it's probably not among the more prioritized back at Mozilla.

Comment: I think this is a great, poorly-executed idea. They could probably use something like section highlighting or graying out, or what have you. But a scroll bar is the wrong kind of indicator here simply because so many people have a different idea as to its purpose.